# Given two martingals sum also martingal?

Tags: probability, martingales

Let $X_{n}, Y_{n}$ be independent martingals. Is it also the case that $X_{n} + Y_{n}$  is a martingale? And if we drop the independence condition does ist also define a martingal?

Comment: okay...thanks. But what if $X_{n}$ and $Y_{n}$ are not independet?

Comment: Then, in general, the sum fails to be a martingale. Just take a look at the other question; it's all explained there. (....I doubt that you read it within 3 minutes.....)

Comment: It will, of course, depend on your filtration

Comment: can you give an exampple of a filtration such that $X_{n}, Y_{n}$ are dependent and the sum is a martingal?

Comment: $X_n = Y_n = X$ for some integrable random variable $X$; $\mathcal{F}_n := \sigma(X)$.